# PHP Doamin based licensing system

Tags: php, file, error-handling

I tried to create a domain based licensing system. The script should be check for license each time it'll be run. I'll use two domains which are hosted in two different servers and networks so that if a server is down, another one will help the scripts for licensing purpose.
Look at the codes bellow...

```
if (file_get_contents("http://domain.com/lic/ok.xml",0,null,0,1) !== false || file_get_contents("http://domain.net/lic/ok.xml",0,null,0,1) !== false) {
echo 'All is well';
} else {
echo 'Error, sorry!';
}
```

And output:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://domain.com/lic/ok.xml) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in C:\wamp\www\ok.php on line 3
All is well
```

I just created a license file in domain.net. In domain.com, there was no "ok.xml". That means if any of the server goes down, the error message like above will be shown. Actually I want to display "All is well" is any of the servers contains the license file.

So how my code should be re-written? Which function should I use? Please help me.

PS: I'm fully new here and not known with rules of this types of community. So please help me to go on. Don't close the topic directly, help me to find out the correct way to post/ask questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@file_get_contents` to suppress errors.

However, doing a remote HTTP request on every page load is pretty much unacceptable. If your server (or one of them) is slow the site doing the requests will be slow, too.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks a lot.
Actually I'll use the code into a WordPress Plugin. So when users will try to activate the plugin, license will be checked. Again, when user will access plugins option/settings page, license will be checked. Just it...

Comment: I'll encode with ioncube encoder after completing the script.

Comment: Ok.. so even less users since not everyone has installed ioncube on his server. Besides that, a simple /etc/hosts entry will allow to circumvent it

Comment: So what should I use to protect my scripts?

Comment: Nothing. Simply assume most of your users will pay instead of downloading it somewhere. Some people will use cracked versions anyway. Don't waste time/money on protection but on making your software better so more people are likely to buy it.